# UnitTestCase not found in phalcon unit testing

Tags: php

I am running the example from 
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/unit-testing.html
I did all configuration but I am facing with

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject>phpunit tests/UnitTest.php
>
> Fatal error: Class 'UnitTestCase' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\tests\Unit Test.php on line 16

Line 16 is

> class UnitTest extends \UnitTestCase {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your test inside `tests` folder. As mentioned in that tutorial:

> This will run any tests under the tests/ directory.

As you can see from PHPunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./TestHelper.php"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         verbose="true"
         colors="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="true">
    <testsuite name="Phalcon - Testsuite">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

Directory is set to current one `<directory>./</directory>`
So run tests like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\tests>phpunit UnitTest.php
```

Comment: that's work but again I am facing with "Strict standards: Declaration of UnitTestCase::setUp() should be compatible with
 Phalcon\Test\UnitTestCase::setUp(Phalcon\DiInterface $di = NULL, Phalcon\Config"

Comment: @illusionist i cant say for sure, i need to see code